# How to detect and distinguish device pixel density and zoom in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, zooming, pixel-density

How can I detect (in JS in Chrome) the *zoom level* **AND** *device pixel density* (separately), to be able to scale graphics to the level of 1 device px = 1 screen px (to avoid blur) but still allow users to use the browser zoom feature?

Comment: In other words, you want to serve 100% graphics to a user with a 100% system zoom even with a 200% chrome zoom?

Comment: I would not simplify it to "just 100%". Basically I want to have control over how the things are scaled.